# VB #If KeyWord - Effect Of #

Tags: vb.net

Google is not good for searching for the # symbol

What effect does the # in front of the if make?

I am cleaning up someones mess and have never seen this before

Answer (score 3):

Those are directives or "pre-processor directives". They basically allow for conditional compiling of VB code. Here is the VB-related MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is a [Preprocessor Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(VS.71).aspx)

e pre-processing directives provide the ability to conditionally skip sections of source files, to report error and warning conditions, and to delineate distinct regions of source code

Answer (score 2):

> On the surface, the behavior of the
>   `#If...Then...#Else` directives appears the same as that of the
>   If...Then...Else statements. However,
>   the #If...Then...#Else directives
>   evaluate what is compiled by the
>   compiler, whereas the If...Then...Else
>   statements evaluate conditions at run
>   time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `#If...Then...#Else` is a preprocessor directive that allows certain parts of your code to be compiled based on certain conditions.

It functions just like a regular `If...Then...Else` statement but the difference is that the condition is evaluated when the program is being compiled. this results in some portions of the code not being compiled.

The `#If` can be useful when you want some code to be compiled for Debug versions of your application but not for the release. Take for example the code below. By writing the code below, the `Beep()` section will be compiled in Debug mode but when the project's output type is changed to Release, that section will not be compiled.

```
#If DEBUG Then
        'beep once in debug mode
        Beep()
#Else
        'do nothing
#End If
```

The `#If` directive works with [Conditional Compilation Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deszhz3d.aspx). These are the 'variables' that are evaluated at compile time to determine which parts of your code to compile.

In a standard project you have the following conditional compilation directives:

- **CONFIG:** (String) Either *Debug* or *Release*
- **DEBUG:** (int32, *can evaluate as boolean*) -1 (or *True*) if project configuration is debug.
- **PLATFORM:** (String) *x86* or *x64* for 32-bit or 64-bit compilation mode respectively.
- **TARGET:** (string) *winexe* for Windows Forms Application and Windows Service, *exe* for Console Applications and *library* for Class Library and Web Control Library
- **TRACE:** (int32, *can evaluate as boolean*) -1 (or *True*) if Trace constant is defined.
- **VBC_VER:** (double? *not sure) Indicates the version number of the VB.NET compiler.

Using these conditional compilation directives, you can easily have certain parts of your code compile into the output or not.

#### Further Reading:

- [Conditional Compilation in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x435tkbk.aspx)
- [#If...Then...#Else Directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx)
- [#Const Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/deszhz3d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The #If/#Else/#EndIf directives may be used to tell the compiler, Intellisense, etc. to ignore sections of code.  If one encloses some code in an "If False Then ... End If" statement, the code will never execute, but the compiler will still process it, and Intellisense will still update it.  If part of a program is surrounded by "#If False ... #EndIf", it will be essentially regarded as comments.  There is no requirement that the stuff within a "#If False" directive be syntactically valid, and tools like "Rename variable" will not affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an examlpe (other has allready answered WHAT #-directive is):

```
#IF debug=true
 userhandler.login("stefan","mypassword")
#else
 userhandler.login(usernameTextbox.text,userpasswordTextbox.text)
#end if
```

When you run your code in debug mode the compiler will automatically handle the code in the true-part of the IF-condition. When you set the project to release and rebuild the project, it will use the other part of the if-condition. That way you can make the live as a programmer more easy for testing purposes and much other scenarios.